# How to obtain remote acess at an vmware machine

Tags: vmware, remote-access, vmware-workstation, remote-control, vmware-server

I have 2 vmware machines and i want to acess them from another pc from another network.

You can teal me what software i have to install to achive remote control on this 2 vmware machines?

This 2 vmware machines run under vmware workstation 15 pro.

Comment: Have you given Teamviewer any thought?

Comment: @MadWard, Yes but în teamviwer i have a great delay, I want to use a vmware service if any exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Workstation installed on the second physical machine, you should be able to follow the following instructions and connect to those running VMs, as well as manage them as if they were running, on that second physical machine: https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-35036F2B-8C5D-4F61-A64D-BE8C2290F09A.html